# unset data when running second loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to create simple poll system. I have two question and two answers. First Question has two answer but second question hasn't any answer. In a sense I want to get:

```
First question?
Answer1
Answer2

Second question?
```

But I'm getting

```
First question?
Answer1
Answer2

Second question?
Answer1 
Answer2
```

Second question need not to have Answer1 and Answer2(same with First question answers but I have two answer in mysql).

And my foreach loops.. How need i to change my loops?

```
foreach($sorular->soruCek($_GET["kategori"]) as $data) // Questions
{
    echo $data["soru"] . "<br/>";
    foreach($sorular->cevapCek($data["id"]) as $cevaplar) // Answers
    {
        echo $cevaplar["cevap"] . "<br/>"; // This needn't print data to below of Second Question
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time, consider localizing your example code :) plus your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Use `unset($var);` if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($sorular->soruCek($_GET["kategori"]) as $data)
{
    $inner_data = $sorular->cevapCek($data["id"]);

    if ($inner_data) {
        echo $data["soru"] . "<br/>";

        foreach($inner_data as $cevaplar)
        {
            echo $cevaplar["cevap"] . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

You have to fetch the data inside the inner loop first, make sure it has values before printing the - what I assume is - a header?

Comment: @Birlikisgu i don't understand what you mean

Comment: @Birlikisgu I'm afraid I have no idea then, because I can't correlate  the code written and the output :(

Comment: can you read my question again? Because I cleared my question.

Comment: @Birlikisgu okay, but your `$sorular->cevapCek($data["id"])` is linked to the question id, so if you see two answers there your mysql query is probably wrong

Answer (score 0):

For unsetting a variable , you could use

```
unset($yourvariable);
```

Using  `unset()` would destroy the specified variables.